# How to convert this Annotation based to functional in spring-cloud-streams

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have the below classes, I am upgrading stream from 2.x to 3.2.4. Can someone please help me with the migration process.

```
public interface EventStreams {
String LOG_EVENT_INGEST = "ingest";
String ELASTICSEARCH_PUBLISH = "esPublish";

@Input(LOG_EVENT_INGEST)                          - deprecated
public SubscribableChannel logEventIngest();

@Output(ELASTICSEARCH_PUBLISH)                   - deprecated
public MessageChannel esPublish();
 }
```

...

Service

```
 @Component
 @EnableBinding(EventStreams.class)          - deprecated
 public class EventService {
@Autowired
MessageChannel headerEnrichmentChannel;

@Autowired
MessageChannel rejectChannel;


@StreamListener(EventStreams.LOG_EVENT_INGEST)    - deprecated
```

service.workflow.service

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(EventStreams.class)                          - deprecated
public class ElasticSearchService {

@Autowired
EventStreams eventSteams;

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "esServiceChannel", requiresReply = "false")
```

Comment: Please read the binding section - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_bindings. Nothing really changed except that bindings are now "implied" which means you don't have to define them explicitly like you do in the example above. Nothing else changed

Comment: Thanks @@Oleg Zhurakousky , But when I remove the "@Enablebinding" it is asking to define a bean - Consider defining a bean of type 'EventStreams' in your configuration. With "@Enablebinding"it says 'Functional binding is disabled due to the presense of "@Enablebinding" annotation in your configuration'

Comment: So, you have other `Enablebinding` present in your configuration. That would not work